# using lambda or list comprehesion to create list with loop

Tags: python, python-3.6

for the following code, how I can write into one line using lambda function or using python list comprehension?

```
def f():
    lst=[]
    for i in range(1, 101):
        if i < 50:
            lst.append('A')
        else:
            lst.append('B')
    return lst
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that your function outputs 49 `'A'`s and 51 `'B'`s. I'm not sure if that's intentional.

The easiest way to get 50/50 would be :

```
['A'] * 50 + ['B'] * 50
```

If you want to define a lambda:

```
>>> a_or_b = lambda x: 'AB'[x>50]
>>> [a_or_b(x) for x in range(1,101)]
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
```

As a one-liner :

```
['AB'[x>50] for x in range(1,101)]
```

or

```
['AB'[x>=50] for x in range(100)]
```

Those comprehensions use the fact that `False` is `0` and `True` is `1`, and that `'AB'[0]` is `'A'` and 'AB'[1]`is`'B'`.

Comment: This idiom `'AB'[x>50]` is very cryptic, and nowadays that conditional expressions exist those should probably be preferred.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I probably spent too much time on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ :D. Anyway, I added some explanation and as far as simplicity goes, I dare say `['A'] * 50 + ['B'] * 50` is hard to beat (With the added benefit that it's hard to hide an off-by-one error).

Comment: From what I understand, it was the go-to idiom for reproducing "ternary operators" in Python before conditional expressions were introduced. You see it in a lot of old python code-bases.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a ternary conditional in a list comprehension:

```
lst = ['A' if i < 50 else 'B' for i in range(1, 101)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The code, mirroring yours, would be like this:

```
def f():
    return ['A' if i < 50 else 'B' for i in range(1,101)]
```